# how to get contact number in kotlin with compose

Tags: kotlin, contacts

I need to get the contact number of someone from the contact list, without being in an activity and in compose.

I've tried many tutorials but all used activitys or didn't work.

I'm new to programming and if anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you developing for Android? If you are, then you *are* using an Activity even if you’re using Compose.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.